# Checking if a binary tree is symmetric around its centre- how to print node values as a debug?

Tags: python, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I am writing code to solve the following leetcode problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/

The problem in a nutshell is "Given the root of a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (i.e., symmetric around its center)."

```
from collections import deque
class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        queue= deque()
        if not root:
            return []
        #add left and right child of root to start (if root is not None)
        if root.left: 
            queue.append(root.left)
        if root.right: 
            queue.append(root.right)

        right_subt = []
        left_subt = []

        while queue:
            level_length = len(queue)
            #iterate over each level of the tree and add left subtree to left_subt and right subtree to right_subt

            for _ in range((level_length//2)+1):
                node = queue.popleft()
                left_subt.append(node.val)
                if node.left:
                    queue.append(node.left)
                if node.right:
                    queue.append(node.right)
            for _ in range((level_length-(level_length//2))+1):
                node = queue.popleft()
                right_subt.append(node.val)
                if node.left:
                    queue.append(node.left)
                if node.right:
                    queue.append(node.right)
            #compare left and right subtree at each level to check if they're the same
            if left_subt !=right_subt.reverse():
                return False
            #reinitialize left and right subtree lists
            left_subt = []
            right_subt = []
        return True
```

I have run the algorithm with the following `input: [1,2,2,3,4,4,3]` ; it is the input that you see at the top of the page when you click on the link to Leetcode above.

It is returning `false` when it should be returning `true`. When I run the input on paper it seems to work, but unlike arrays/strings, I am not sure how to `print` node values at each stage. Any ideas how to do this, or can someone please outline where the code falls short?

Comment: You could use ```print(node.val)``` to print the values of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to print node values at each stage.

printing values in python is as easy as:

```
print(<something>)
```

where `<something>` is whatever you need to print

for debug purposes you can at any point in your code add for example:

```
print(node.val)
```

or

```
print(queue)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I input the argument? Because the input provided on leetcode is a list, but above it expects a 'root'. The two aren't compatible.

Comment: Generally speaking I am familiar with print()

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question. Wherever you use `node.val` you can use `print(node.val)`. This should help you debug the issue you are having

Answer (score 0):

At least the following snippet will not work as you expected

```
for _ in range((level_length//2)+1):
    node = queue.popleft()
    left_subt.append(node.val)
    if node.left:
        queue.append(node.left)
    if node.right:
        queue.append(node.right)
```

Right at the 1st loop, at which, level_length == 2 (assume that both root.left & root.right are not None )

-> `(level_length//2)+1` will return (1 + 1)

-> The 1st **for** statement will loop two times, and consume both root.left & root.right in your `queue` before the 2nd **for** statement starts

-> nothing's left for your right_subt

-> In the 2nd **for** statement, queue.popleft() will throw an exception due to the fact that you tried to 'pop from an empty deque'

Comment: Thanks, yes I see it now! I thought range(2) would return 1, but it returns 0 and 1! ...